# How do I make values stay in chekbox?

Tags: php

How do I make the values stay in checkboxes?

my problem is when I submit the form the values do not stay (in the form).

Below is my code :

```
Mca<input type="checkbox" name="qual[]" id="Mca" value="Mca" 
           <?php if($qual == "Mca") { echo ' checked="checked"' ; } ?>>
 Mtech<input type="checkbox" name="qual[]" id="Mtech" value="Mtech" 
          <?php if($qual == "Mtech") { echo "checked"; } ?>>
 Btech<input type="checkbox" name="qual[]" id="Btech" value="Btech" 
          <?php if($qual == "Btech") { echo "checked"; } ?>>
```

Comment: What is the value of `$qual` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this because `$qual` is an array.

```
/* Your $qual should be */ <?php $qual = $GET['qual']; ?>

<?php if($qual == "Mca")
```

must be changed to :

```
<?php if(in_array("Mca",$qual)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using better code for your form:

```
<?php

$checkboxes = array('Mca', 'Mtech', 'Btech');

foreach($checkboxes as $k => $v){

echo '<input '.($v==$qual[$k]? 'checked="checked" ': '').'type="checkbox" name="qual[]" id="'.$v.'" value="'.$v.'">';

}
?>
```